# Uber data analysis using databricks pyspark throwing suspicious error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

Uber problem asked to find the days on which each basement has more trips. The schema and 2 rows of data is as given in the image below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvPvE.png)

The code I used below but not able to execute the last line "finaldf.show(). Here is the screenshot of the error. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJ5nC.png)

Need  help

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr, sum, rank
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("first") \
    .getOrCreate()

df1 = spark.read.format("csv") \
    .option("header", "true") \
    .load("dbfs:/FileStore/tables/uber.csv")

df2 = df1.withColumn("trips",col("trips").cast("integer"))

finaldf = df2.withColumn("Day", expr("DATE_FORMAT(TO_DATE(DATE,'MM/dd/yyyy'),'EEE')")) \
    .groupBy("dispatching_base_number", "Day") \
    .agg(sum("trips")).alias("Sum") \
    .withColumn("rnk", rank().over(Window.partitionBy("dispatching_base_number").orderBy("Sum"))) \
    .filter("rnk = 1") \
    .drop("rnk")


finaldf.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please have a look at how to ask a good question here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. For example, what error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Even I got same error when I ran your code.

[image]

That is because your **date** input is `1/1/2017` and giving
expression as `MM/dd/yyyy`. You need to give like this `M/d/yyyy`

Code:

```
finaldf = data.withColumn("Day", expr("DATE_FORMAT(TO_DATE(DATE,'M/d/yyyy'),'EEE')")) \
.groupBy("dispatching_base_number", "Day") \
.agg(sum("trips").alias("Sum")) \
.withColumn("rnk", rank().over(Window.partitionBy("dispatching_base_number").orderBy("Sum"))) \
.filter("rnk =  1") \
.drop("rnk")

finaldf.show()
```

Output:

[image]